# Checking on 3 criteria

Tags: java, exception, char, boolean

i am trying to check on 3 condition to validate a car plate number. But i just cant seems to check all 3 conditions. length must be between 4 -7. first 3 char must be from a - z. fourth char onwards must be digits '0' - '9'.

I have problem on the next part of my question. i need to implement compute CheckDigit method which i have tried to add in an array to accept the arguement for me to do the step by step instruction to compute the check digits.

Below is the steps,

1. take 2nd & 3rd char and convert is to numbers that correspond to the alphabet. eg. A is 1 B is 2.
2. add 0 to the front of the numbers is the numbers has less den 4 digits. eg. SBA123 need to append to 0123
3. multiply each digits in step 1 and 2 by 14,2,12,2,11,1
4. sum up number from step 3
5. divide sum in step 4 by 19 and take remainder and find the check digit in a table.

Any help will be great for me to start. 
below is my code i have change,

Kindly point out my mistake.

```
public static void validateCarPlate(String y)throws InvalidCarPlateException{
String rex = "[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}";
if(y.matches(rex)){
    computeCheckDigit(y);
}else{
    throw new InvalidCarPlateException();
}
}
public static void computeCheckDigit(String x){
int [] arr = Integer.parseInt(x);

}
```

Comment: A regular expression will be more effective

Comment: Can you tell us if these plates are valid or not: AB11, A111, ABC1 ?

Comment: He did define things so we can answer this: first two are invalid (do not have letters as first 3) and 3rd is all right (letters in first three (case problem?), digit at end.  Length is defined to run from 4-7, so we know it's all right to have 1-4 digits.

Comment: @TheEwook rcook is correct. Thanks alot. this really solve part of my problem. Now the next part is also confusing to me=)

Answer (score 2):

The use of **[Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)** would be ideal here. Regular Expressions are funny looking, well constructed strings that represent a **[Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_automaton)** that recognizes certain types of strings as matching a pattern or not matching. Learning about regular expressions will greatly improve your string matching/validation processes.

This is the *RegEx* you should use: `^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}$`

Lets break down what this funny looking string means:

- `^` : This is the start of the string (no characters before it)
- `[a-zA-Z]` : Alphabetic characters
- `{3}` : Exactly 3 of these alphabetic characters
- `[0-9]` : Then numeric characters
- `{1,4}` : Between 1 and 4 of these numeric characters (inclusively)
- `$` : This is the end of the string (no characters remaining)

An example usage:

```
String myStr = "abc123";
System.out.println(isValidString(myStr));

public boolean isValidString(String input) {
  String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}$";
  if(input==null) { return false; }
  return input.trim().matches(regex);
}
```

Comment: For better performance it should be `static final Pattern PLATE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}$");` and `return PLATE_REGEX.matcher(input).matches();`.

Comment: @Cebence Your approach is more efficient, but possibly more difficult for a RegEx beginner to understand.

Comment: Thx guys, REGEX is really useful and it work for my question. But the next step to my question is to use the argument o compute a check digit and return a charcter. i believe i need to use an array and convert all the steps require from there. how do i insert the arguement to an array after using REGEX.

Comment: @LRZJohn edit your question to include the specifications for check-digit requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) very easily, the expression

```
^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}$
```

Would work.

Here is an example

```
public boolean validatePlate(final String string) {
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{1,4}$").matcher(string);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always testing the first character of your string (charAt(0)) instead of using the value of the loop counter i that you set up.  Also, you have no test for the digits.

You could also look into "String.indexOf()"; it would save you having to loop through (or initialize) an array of chars.  Have a string "abcdefg..." (and another "01234...").

You could also look into the methods `Character.isLetter()` and `Character.isDigit()` and do away with the arrays and the strings-treated-like-arrays.

As for regular expressions, I always like the old joke: "Say you have a problem, and you decide to solve it with regular expressions.  Now you have two problems..."  Of course they're useful, but not nearly as much as many people seem to think they are.  And not everything that CAN be solved with them SHOULD be solved with them.  If you're interested, this is a nice simple regular expression problem to get started with.  If you're not, don't feel like your solution is lacking somehow.